# Writing Magento 2 Unit Tests

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, phpunit

I have written unit tests for a custom module which i have created.
I have put the test in the Module directory like the core modules.

Now the tricky part is that,`dev\tests\functional\tests\app` directory also contains the test for the core modules,i also noticed that some of the modules are not included in that directory.
I assumed that they are generated using some command, but i could not find anything that generates them.

So the question is, do we need to write the unit tests twice? or is there any command for generating the tests in the `dev\tests\functional\tests\app` directory?

If we do not need to include the tests in the said directory, how to run the test for single module?

Comment: @FireBear, thank you, yes, i got the answer for how to run the unit test for an individual module, however, i am not yet clear why there is another test for module in `dev\tests\functional` directory?

Comment: Are they different?